# columns must have matching element counts pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

ValueError: columns must have matching element counts

here is my datframe look like:

```
                product title                    variation_list
 Chauvet DJ GigBar Move Effect Light System       ['Black', 'White']
 Pioneer DJ DJM-S11 Professional DJ Mixer          []
 DJM-S11 Professional DJ                           []
 Pioneer DJ                                        ['black']
 dj        

                                    ['white','blue','red']
```

here is my code:

```
 df[['short_des_list']] = df[['short_des_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
 df[['variation_list']] = df[['variation_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
 df[['price_list']] = df[['price_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
    
 df = df.explode(['short_des_list','variation_list','price_list'])
```

error which I am getting:

```
    ValueError: columns must have matching element counts


ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
```

my expected result:

```
                product title                    variation_list
 Chauvet DJ GigBar Move Effect Light System       Black
 Chauvet DJ GigBar Move Effect Light System       White
 Pioneer DJ DJM-S11 Professional DJ Mixer          []
 DJM-S11 Professional DJ                           []
 Pioneer DJ                                      black
 dj                                              white
 dj                                              blue
 dj                                              red
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you provide some expected results?

Comment: ArchAngelPwn see my updated question

Comment: you did not specify what are the values of the two columns short_des_list and price_list

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product' : ['Chauvet DJ GigBar Move Effect Light System', 'Pioneer DJ DJM-S11 Professional DJ Mixer', 'DJM-S11 Professional DJ', 'Pioneer DJ', 'dj'],
    'variation_list' : [['Black', 'White'], [], [], ['black'], ['white', 'blue', 'red']]
})
df = df.explode('variation_list')
df['variation_list'] = df['variation_list'].replace(np.nan, '[]')
df
```